# Function in React isn't firing after 'enter' key is pressed

Tags: reactjs

I want it so after the user hits enter in an input field it fires a function. It  wont' fire the function however. Also before anyone asks I've tested the logic when I hit 'Enter' and I do a console log test it says I hit the 'Enter' key but when I try to call the function it doesn't fire.

The Offending Input Field

```
<input className='chat-input' onKeyUp={(e) => e.key === 'Enter' ? this.handleChat : null}></input>
```

The function

Its located before render so where it should be. There are no errors, crashes and nothing else in the application changes or is acting weird.

```
  handleChat = () => {
    console.log('You called handleChat!!!');
  }
```

Comment: Is it a stateless component where you are trying to run this? If so then change the this.handleChat into handleChat() if it is a stateful component try this.handleChat() i think you are missing the paranthesis.

Comment: Omg I thought I tried that! I've done hundreds of functions like this and I forgot :/

Comment: Haha no worries glad i could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't conditionally set the OnKeyUp value, you should conditionally call it. Something like so:

```
<input className='chat-input' onKeyUp={(e) => {if (e.key === 'Enter') this.handleChat()}}></input>
```

Not sure if those curly braces are right, but you get the idea

Comment: He's using a shorthand if, same as what you wrote here.

Comment: I know what a ternary operator is. Whether I gave a ternary or plain if statement in my answer, the if syntax wasn't the important part anyway. It's that he wasn't actually *calling* the function. Which was the answer to his problem, as you've seen in your comments. Correct answers shouldn't be downvoted cos their syntax is slightly different to OP's.

Comment: this is a right answer, op should call handleChat not just set it. whoever downvoted it should read it again more carefully.